# $.getJSON data is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, foreach, getjson

I'm getting JSON data from the iTunes API but when even I console.log my data it says its undefined, am I doing something wrong?

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=angry&limit=4&media=software&callback=?",function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            console.log(element.artistName);
        });
    }); 
});
```

JSON

```
jQuery19108565351243602318_1364012908350(
{
 "resultCount":1,
 "results": [
{"kind":"software", "features":["gameCenter"], "supportedDevices":["iPad3G", "iPodTouchourthGen", "iPhone-3GS", "iPodTouchThirdGen", "iPad23G", "iPhone4", "iPadWifi", "iPad2Wifi"], "isGameCenterEnabled":true, 
"screenshotUrls":["http://a786.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/069/Purple2/v4/61/c6/55/61c655ac-5c32-c9d6-61c1-d4025c5822ed/mzl.babhynjf.png", "http://a1425.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/061/Purple/v4/c1/f3/51/c1f35156-fc04-bd31-bb92-b695043e922c/mzl.vzvfrzpz.png", "http://a712.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/068/Purple2/v4/ea/40/5a/ea405a80-c31d-6061-cc7c-3f88d4d80659/mzl.zmdognad.png", "http://a1974.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/063/Purple/v4/c1/b1/53/c1b153df-3657-1b84-350d-257201dab7b2/mzl.qwyhrzas.png", "http://a294.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/061/Purple2/v4/c2/b0/d2/c2b0d22c-a3fe-0afc-8766-3def3d3bac57/mzl.szsfyhqo.png"], "ipadScreenshotUrls":[], "artworkUrl60":"http://a1102.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/061/Purple2/v4/49/b6/7d/49b67d81-a95a-bbee-fc02-486f8ee174d8/Icon.png", "artworkUrl512":"http://a141.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/105/Purple2/v4/9a/2a/1e/9a2a1e43-fbd5-32d7-53c7-9490d77ce891/mzl.wepjpyjw.png", "artistViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/rovio-entertainment-ltd/id298910979?uo=4", "artistId":298910979, "artistName":"Rovio Entertainment Ltd", "price":0.99, "version":"3.1.0", 
"description":"Use the unique powers of the Angry Birds to destroy the greedy pigs' defenses!\u2028\u2028\n\nThe survival of the Angry Birds is at stake. Dish out revenge on the greedy pigs who stole their eggs. Use the unique powers of each bird to destroy the pigs\u2019 defenses. Angry Birds features challenging physics-based gameplay and hours of replay value. Each level requires logic, skill and force to solve.\u2028\u2028\n\nIf you get stuck in the game, you can purchase the Mighty Eagle! Mighty Eagle is a one-time in-app purchase in Angry Birds that gives unlimited use. This phenomenal creature will soar from the skies to wreak havoc and smash the pesky pigs into oblivion. There\u2019s just one catch: you can only use the aid of Mighty Eagle to pass a level once per hour. Mighty Eagle also includes all new gameplay goals and achievements!\u2028\u2028\n\nIn addition to the Mighty Eagle, Angry Birds now has power-ups! Boost your birds\u2019 abilities and three-star levels to unlock secret content! Angry Birds now has the following amazing power-ups: Sling Scope for laser targeting, King Sling for maximum flinging power, Super Seeds to supersize your birds, and Birdquake to shake pigs\u2019 defenses to the ground!\u2028\u2028\n\n#1 IPHONE PAID APP in US, UK, Canada, Italy, Germany, Russia, Sweden, Denmark, Finland, Singapore, Poland, France, Netherlands, Malta, Greece, Austria, Australia, Turkey, UAE, Saudi Arabia, Israel, Belgium, Norway, Hungary, Malaysia, Luxembourg, Portugal, Czech Republic, Spain, Ireland, Romania, New Zealand, Latvia, Lithuania, Estonia, Nicaragua, Kazakhstan, Argentina, Bulgaria, Slovakia, Slovenia, Mauritius, Chile, Hong Kong, Pakistan, Taiwan, Colombia, Indonesia, Thailand, India, Kenya, Macedonia, Croatia, Macau, Paraguay, Peru, Armenia, Philippines, Vietnam, Jordan and Kuwait. \u2028\u2028\n\nNote: if you are having a problem with your device crashing after installing the update, try shutting down and restarting the device. If you are still having problems, contact support@rovio.com.\n\n#1 IPHONE PAID GAME in more countries than we can count!\n\nTerms of Use: http://www.rovio.com/eula\u2028\nPrivacy Policy: http://www.rovio.com/privacy\u2028\n\nThis application may require internet connectivity and subsequent data transfer charges may apply.", "currency":"USD", "genres":["Games", "Entertainment", "Action", "Arcade"], "genreIds":["6014", "6016", "7001", "7003"], "releaseDate":"2009-12-11T08:00:00Z", "sellerName":"Rovio Entertainment Ltd", "bundleId":"com.clickgamer.AngryBirds", "trackId":343200656, "trackName":"Angry Birds", "primaryGenreName":"Games", "primaryGenreId":6014, "releaseNotes":"Check out 15 fantastic new levels for the Bad Piggies episode! OINK!", "formattedPrice":"$0.99", "wrapperType":"software", "trackCensoredName":"Angry Birds", "languageCodesISO2A":["EN"], "fileSizeBytes":"35746968", "sellerUrl":"http://www.angrybirds.com/", "contentAdvisoryRating":"4+", "averageUserRatingForCurrentVersion":4.5, "userRatingCountForCurrentVersion":1302, "artworkUrl100":"http://a141.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/105/Purple2/v4/9a/2a/1e/9a2a1e43-fbd5-32d7-53c7-9490d77ce891/mzl.wepjpyjw.png", "trackViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds/id343200656?mt=8&uo=4", "trackContentRating":"4+", "averageUserRating":4.5, "userRatingCount":821819}]
}
);
```

Comment: `element.results.artistName`..???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
$.each(data.results, function(index, element) {
    console.log(element.artistName);
});
```

The `data` is a object with two properties `resultCount` and `results`, the actual data array is stored with in the `results`, so you need to iterate through `data.results` instead of `data`.